# aggregate daily total in sas

Tags: sas, finance

I'm looking to find the total daily market cap of a stock exchange. So far I have calculated daily market caps for each firm listed and now I'm calculating an aggregated market cap for the exchange.

The code I have used so far is:

`proc means data=index.mrk_cap sum;
    var MarketCap;
    by date;
    output out=Tot_MKT;
    run;`

This generates daily market caps but only in a project form output and I would like my data to be usable in a data set. Any modifications that would let me create daily market caps would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `sum` keyword on the `output` statement.

```
output out=Tot_MKT sum(MarketCap)=mktCap_Sum;
```

`Output` doesn't by default create any variables; you have to specify exactly what you want output to the dataset.  There are a wealth of papers on the subject available (search http://lexjansen.com/ or http://sas.com/ for examples).

Comment: Thanks Joe. I get what I've missed, still getting the hang of it all. Thanks for the jansen link.